# Will `recv` block on a TCP socket when I request more data than is immediately available?

Tags: sockets, tcp, recv

TCP can arbitrarily merge and split packets. So, assuming I do, for example, such a call:

```
`recv(sock, buf, 15, 0)`
```

But at this moment only `5` bytes of data is immediately available –

Will `recv()` block until `15`bytes of data is available, or will I get only `5` bytes?

I'm asking because I'd like to know if I can read, for example, a `uint32_t` simply this way (assuming `i` is a variable of type `uint32_t`):

```
if(recv(sock, &i, sizeof(uint32_t), 0) < sizeof(uint32_t)) {
    /* error */
}
i = ntohl(i);
```

Or do I rather have to do something like that:

```
unsigned char buff[sizeof(uint32_t)];
ssize_t read_already = 0;
while(read_already != sizeof(uint32_t)) {
    ssize_t read_now = recv(sock, buff, sizeof(uint32_t)-read_already, 0);
    if(read_now == -1) {
        /* error */
    }
    else {
        read_already += read_now;
    }
}
memcpy(&i, buff, sizeof(uint32_t));
i = ntohl(i);
```

The latter is noticeably uglier and more arduous, but sadly necessary if `recv()` doesn't block until it receives all requested data in case the package gets split.

Answer (score 1):

In general, without any special flags, socket options, or ioctls being set, a `recv` call on a blocking TCP socket will return any number of bytes less than or equal to the size being requested.  But unless the socket is closed remotely, interrupted by signal, or in an error state, it will block until at least 1 byte is available.

In other words, if you ask for 15 bytes, but only 5 are available, `recv` will return 5.

Application developers should not rely on how the data was sent or constructed and treat their socket as capable of returning a partial stream of data at any time. (Or as I tell others, write your code as if it was possible that `recv` only returned 1 byte at a time).

A common loop for receiving data often looks like the following. Notice the pointer math done on `buffer` in the recv call.

```
unsigned char buffer[bytes_expected];
ssize_t bytes_received = 0;
while (bytes_received < bytes_expected)
{
    int result = recv(sock, buffer + bytes_received, bytes_expected-bytes_received, 0);
    if (result == 0)
    {
        // socket was closed remotely - break out of the loop
    }
    else if (result < 0)
    {
        // socket was closed on remote end or hit an error
        // either way, the socket is likely dead
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        bytes_received += result;
    }
}
```

The exception to this rule that I know is the `MSG_WAITALL` flag based as the last parameter to `recv`.   That will hold the socket (block) until you get all the bytes requested by the `length` parameter passed to `recv` (or until error or socket close).

From the [man page for recv](https://linux.die.net/man/2/recv):

> MSG_WAITALL (since Linux 2.2)  This flag requests that the operation
>   block until the full request is satisfied. However, the call may still
>   return less data than requested if a signal is caught, an error or
>   disconnect occurs, or the next data to be received is of a different
>   type than that returned

The fact that you are even asked this question puts you in a league above most others who are new to sockets.  So much buggy code exists in the real world because most developers didn't handle the case of recv returning something less than expected.

Comment: Thank you. So, there is no escape from the ugliness and arduousness of my second snippet?

Comment: `MSG_WAITALL` might meet your needs.  There's a bug in your snippet (you didn't do the pointer math on `buff` in your question).  See the code sample I provided.