# Trying to send a FIX api message to ctrader server using Ruby but receiving no response

Tags: ruby, fix-protocol, tcpsocket

Trying to see if I can get a response from ctrader server.

Getting no response and seems to hang at "s.recv(1024)". So not sure what could be going wrong here. 
I have limited experience with sockets and network coding.

I have checked my login credentials and all seems ok.

Note: I am aware of many FIX engines that are available for this purpose but wanted to
try this on my own.

[ctrader FIX guides](https://help.ctrader.com/fix)

```
require 'socket'

hostname = "h51.p.ctrader.com"
port = 5201

#constructing a fix message to see what ctrader server returns
#8=FIX.4.4|9=123|35=A|49=demo.ctrader.*******|56=cServer|57=QUOTE|50=QUOTE|34=1|52=20220127-16:49:31|98=0|108=30|553=********|554=*******|10=155|

fix_message = "8=FIX.4.4|9=#{bodylengthsum}|" + bodylength + "10=#{checksumcalc}|"

s = TCPSocket.new(hostname, port)
s.send(fix_message.force_encoding("ASCII"),0)
print fix_message 
puts s.recv(1024)
s.close
```

Comment: I've never worked with the FIX protocol, and I don't do much socket programming either, but it looks like `send` and `recv` might be the low-level methods. Have you tried higher-level methods like `print` and `read`?

Comment: @JaredBeck hmmm...i guess its worth a shot. Let me try them

Comment: tried the higher level methods but had no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sockets are by default blocking on read. When you call `recv` that call will block if no data is available.

The fact that your `recv` call is not returning anything, would be an indication that the server did not send you any reply at all; the call is blocking waiting for incoming data.

If you would use `read` instead, then the call will block until *all* the requested data has been received.

So calling `recv(1024)` will block until 1 or more bytes are available.
Calling `read(1024)` will block until all 1024 bytes have been received.

Note that [you cannot rely on a single `recv` call to return a full message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44192144/will-recv-block-on-a-tcp-socket-when-i-request-more-data-than-is-immediately-a), even if the sender sent you everything you need. Multiple `recv` calls may be required to construct the full message.

Also note that the FIX protocol gives the msg length at the start of each message. So after you get enough data to see the msg length, you could call `read` to ensure you get the rest.

If you do not want your `recv` or `read` calls to block when no data (or incomplete data) is available, then you need to use non-blocking IO instead for your reads. This is complex topic, which you need to research, but often used when you don't want to block and need to read arbitary length messages. You can [look here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Reference/Objects/Socket) for some tips.

Another option would be to use something like [EventMachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine) instead, which makes it easier to deal with sockets in situations like this, without having to worry about blocking in your code.

Comment: I'm confused, because `BasicSocket#recv` is *non*-blocking. For example, `UNIXSocket.pair {|s1, s2| s1.print 'hello'; s2.recv(999) } #=> "hello"`. It definitely doesn't wait for 999 bytes. So, if the OP's socket's are blocking, then why is `UNIXSocket#recv` non-blocking? Just curious, thanks.

Comment: @JaredBeck It's a good catch. It looks like I was bit rusty on my socket calls. `recv` will indeed return on any data (it will only block on no data). `read` is the one which will block until the full requested lenth is received. Updated the answer.